# access 2003 text display leading zero

Tags: ms-access

We are currently using Access 2003.  I have a vehicle maintenance log which has a text field for vehicle numbers.  The field needs to be text as it will have a R in it when a vehicle is retired.  They would like to have the field be a four digit number with leading zero's.  So vehicle 22 would be displayed in the table and reports as 0022 and when retired it would be R0022.  I have tried to change the format of the field to "0000" and "0000"# but neither of these will display the leading zero's.

Comment: Are you just putting '22' into the text field, or are you entering the whole '0022'? Text fields *should* leave leading zeros alone. I also don't believe that changing the `Format` property will make any difference for a text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want you users to manually edit that field?
I don't like solutions like this, because it's error-prone (unless you check a lot of things to make sure that no one enters invalid data) and feels unelegant to your users.

I would just save the following in the table:

- the vehicle number in a numeric field (`22`, not `0022`)
- a boolean field which indicates if the vehicle is retired

This is much easier for your users to work with:

- they can just enter new vehicle numbers without having to think about leading zeros
- to retire a vehicle, they just need to set a checkbox, instead of putting the right letter in front of the vehicle number

Plus, showing the desired number `R0022` now becomes just a matter of displaying/formatting the data from the table:

```
Public Function GetDisplayNo(VehicleNo As Integer, IsRetired As Boolean) As String

    GetDisplayNo = IIf(IsRetired, "R", "") & Right("0000" & VehicleNo, 4)

End Function
```

You can use this function like this:

`GetDisplayNo(22, True)` returns `R0022`

`GetDisplayNo(22, False)` returns `0022`

And if you need to display a list of vehicle numbers in a report or a continuous form, you can directly use this function in the underlying query:

```
SELECT 
    Vehicles.VehicleNo, 
    Vehicles.IsRetired,
    GetDisplayNo([VehicleNo],[IsRetired]) AS DisplayNumber
FROM Vehicles;
```