# Associating a counter to different combinations of values obtained from comboboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a macro that obtains entries associated to 2 comboboxes, and joins them in a textbox, with an index related to the record number:

```
Private Sub N_Licence_Click()
    If Me.City.Column(2) = "" Or Me.Type.Column(2) = "" Then
    Me.N_Licence = ""
    Else
    Me.N_Licence = Me.City.Column(2) & "-" & Me.Type.Column(2) & "-" & Me.Form.CurrentRecord
    End If
    End Sub
```

The result of this is something like this:

```
PARIS-A-1
PARIS-B-2
LYON-C-3
LYON-C-4 
PARIS-A-5
...
```

I would like to associate a counter to each different combination of the 2 first values (instead of a record number associated to the entry) like this:

```
PARIS-A-1
PARIS-B-1
LYON-C-1
LYON-C-2 
PARIS-A-2
...
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In Access 2010 or later you can use a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to assign the sequence numbers. For example, with a table having the following fields

ID - AutoNumber, Primary Key
City - Text
Type - Text
Seq - Long Integer
N_License - Text

the following data macro will derive the next [Seq] value for the given [City] and [Type] values, then build the [N_License] string:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

with results like this

```
ID  City   Type  Seq  N_License
--  -----  ----  ---  ---------
 1  PARIS  A       1  PARIS-A-1
 2  ROME   X       1  ROME-X-1 
 3  ROME   Y       1  ROME-Y-1 
 4  ROME   X       2  ROME-X-2 
 5  PARIS  A       2  PARIS-A-2
 6  PARIS  B       1  PARIS-B-1
 7  PARIS  A       3  PARIS-A-3
```

Comment: I don't have a field to assign sequence numbers in the table, to use this method I must create one, correct? Also I am having dificulties inputting SQL code in "Lookup a record In" it says "SQL statement not valid". Can you convert that example to vba code?

Comment: Creating a separate numeric "seq" field is not absolutely required but it is a cleaner approach than trying to do it all in one alphanumeric field. As for difficulties entering the SQL statement, see the related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20661510/2144390).