# Making custom primary key for access tables

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am looking for a way to make custom primary keys for access tables. What I am looking to do is to make something like 'C01234'. The alphabet at the start has some purpose and hence has to be there.

I know there is a way to use an autonumbered PK field and make a custom field using DMax function. Something like this: [Custom primary key for MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546023/custom-primary-key-for-ms-access). But what I am looking for is to not use another field and generate the alpha numeric PK completely using code.

Is it possible using the Access macro? Is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: What version of Access are you targeting?

Comment: MS Access 2013 is what I use. But no problem I found a solution, or rather I think I got a solution. Still verifying.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a form, then use the BeforeInsert event:

```
Dim Prefix As String
Dim Digits As Integer

Prefix = "C"
Digits = 5

Me!CustomID.Value = Prefix & Right(String(Digits, "0") & CStr(Val(Right(DMax("CustomID", "YourTable", "CustomID Like '" & Prefix & "*'"), Digits)) + 1), Digits)
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the code. I could you use that if I use a form. But now I have found a way to put a macro in the before insert event of the table so that it creates the autonumber no matter where I am inputting the data from ..